# File in project I/O at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

If I have a file, like a .txt file (not a Resource or Content file) in my project that I want to read/write to at runtime, in a debugging session from Visual Studio, what's the simplest way to do that?

Visual Studio has to hold references to these files' locations in order to load them, right? I want to do the same thing.

I'm planning to have hundreds of these files and don't want to set everything to "Content" and "Copy if Newer" in Visual Studio.

Comment: `I'm planning to have hundreds of these files` - you really should consider using a database. Also suggest you get in the habit of tagging questions with the project type: console, winforms, wpf, asp.net otherwise no one can guide you on how to specify the folder path accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your text files under a folder and read them with following code -

```
using System.IO;

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

- .Net Framework 4.0 - `EnumerateFiles`
- .Net Framework Previous versions - `GetFiles`

Comment: @Eric, you may want to know [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), otherwise the question will remain unanswered.